# Pandas set_index() seems to change the types for some rows to <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm observing an unexpected behavior of the Pandas set_index() function.

In order to make my results reproducible I provide my DataFrame as a pickle file [df_test.pkl](https://gofile.io/d/ZUoTw3).

```py
df_test = pd.read_pickle('./df_test.pkl')
```

```
    time            id          avg
0   1554985690182   117455392   4.06300000
1   1554985690288   117455393   0.95800000
2   1554985690641   117455394   2.38400000
...
```

Now, when I iterate over the rows and print the type of each "id" value I get *<class 'numpy.int64'>* for all cells.

```py
for i in df_test.index:
    print(type(df_test.at[i,'id']))
```

```
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
...
```

Now I set the index to the "time" column and everything looks fine.

```py
df_test = df_test.set_index(keys='time', drop=True)
```

```
                id          avg
time            
1554985690182   117455392   4.06300000
1554985690288   117455393   0.95800000
1554985690641   117455394   2.38400000
...
```

But when I iterate again over the rows and print the type of each "id" value I get *<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>* for some cells.

```py
for i in df_test.index:
    print(type(df_test.at[i,'id']))
```

```
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
...
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

**UPDATE:**
I have removed the "id_type" column from the df_test DataFrame, because it was not helpful. Thanks to @Let'stry for making me aware!

Comment: When you call `df_test['id']` you get the type of the whole column, that is a `pandas.core.series.Series`. When you iterate over the column values, you get the individual types of the cells, that is `'numpy.int64'`.

Comment: That's right, but the main question above remains, why the iteration gives different types for some rows before and after set_index()?

Comment: After you set the index, you are calling `type(df_test['id'])`,that is, the type of the column, not the specific cells.

Comment: Yes you're right, let'f forget the "id_type" column, I messed that one up. The main problem is my iteration function above where I call `print(type(df_test.at[i,'id']))` on every row and it provides different types before and after set-index().

Comment: @Let'stry I have updated the example above after your comment. The column "id_type" was really not helpful, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself.

There where duplicate timestamps in the "time" column and it seems that Pandas cannot set_index() properly if there are duplicate values in the selected column. Which makes total sense, because an index with duplicates would be pointless.

By the way, I found this issue by using the argument `verify_integrity=True` in the set_index() function. So I recommend using that argument to avoid this kind of trouble.

```py
df_test = df_test.set_index(keys='time', drop=True, verify_integrity=True)
```

Everything works fine now after I've removed the duplicate rows.